# Lista Categoria e subcaegoria

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde,
Estou desenvolvendo um framework no modelo MvC e queria listar as categorias e as subcategoria estou usando uma unica tabela **CATEGORIA**.
com os seguintes campos.

```
 mysql> select * from ws_categoria;
+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| id_categoria | id_parent | categoria | subcategoria |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|            4 |      NULL | VIATUAS   | NULL         |
|            5 |      NULL | DESPESAS  | NULL         |
|            6 |      NULL | OUTROS    | NULL         |
|            7 |         4 | NULL      | viatura 1    |
|            8 |         4 | NULL      | viatrua 2    |
|            9 |         5 | NULL      | gasolina     |
|           10 |         5 | NULL      | pneus        |
|           11 |         6 | NULL      | Reparacao    |
|           12 |         6 | NULL      | Pintura      |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

so que o problema e quando vou tentar recuperar os dados não consigo separar os dados do tipo.

NA CATEGORIA VIATRUAS trazer so os grupos de viaturas assim como as demais categorias, a query que estou usando é esta.

```
SELECT
app.categoria.categoria,
app.subcategoria.subcategoria
FROM
app.ws_categoria AS subcategoria
JOIN app.ws_categoria AS categoria
ON app.subcategoria.id_parent = app.categoria.id_categoria
```

**RESULTADO**

```
+-----------+--------------+
| categoria | subcategoria |
+-----------+--------------+
| VIATUAS   | viatura 1    |
| VIATUAS   | viatrua 2    |
| DESPESAS  | gasolina     |
| DESPESAS  | pneus        |
| OUTROS    | Reparacao    |
| OUTROS    | Pintura      |
+-----------+--------------+
```

**CONCLUSÃO**

Quando vou tentar recuperar os valores no foreach o resultado que recebo é este:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[13]
      public 'categoria' => string 'VIATUAS' (length=7)
      public 'subcategoria' => string 'viatura 1' (length=9)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[14]
      public 'categoria' => string 'VIATUAS' (length=7)
      public 'subcategoria' => string 'viatrua 2' (length=9)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[15]
      public 'categoria' => string 'DESPESAS' (length=8)
      public 'subcategoria' => string 'gasolina' (length=8)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[16]
      public 'categoria' => string 'DESPESAS' (length=8)
      public 'subcategoria' => string 'pneus' (length=5)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'categoria' => string 'OUTROS' (length=6)
      public 'subcategoria' => string 'Reparacao' (length=9)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[18]
      public 'categoria' => string 'OUTROS' (length=6)
      public 'subcategoria' => string 'Pintura' (length=7)
```

Comment: posso estar errado e não ter entendido sua pergunta, mas creio que tu esteja realizando o relacionamento de banco de dados incorretamente, você deveria criar uma tabela para CATEGORIA e outra para SUBCATEGORIA, pois na minha concessão a CATEGORIA pode ter várias SUBCATEGORIA, então você deveria relacionar a tabela SUBCATEGORIA com a tabela CATEGORIA, ou seja, cada categoria cadastrada você deve informar uma categoria exclusiva.

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela dica. :)

Comment: Sabe como fazer ou gostaria de um exemplo?

Comment: crie uma tabela categorias e uma subcategorias e na tabela subcategorias coloque o id da tabela categorias  na tabela subcategorias, e nomeie o campo de uma forma simples como esta => id_subcategoria e ai sim relacione através de categoria.id = subcategoria.id_categoria

Comment: Obrigado amigo obrigado pelo exemplo. pensei que daria para fazer relacionamentos de tabela de 1:1 com ela mesma. XD

Comment: na verdade N subcategorias podem pertencem a 1 categoria, já 1 categoria não pode pertencem a N subcategorias, então é CATEGORIA 1 PARA N SUBCATEGORIAS

Answer (score 0):

```
|         CATEGORIA       |          SUBCATEGORIA
|                         |
| ID - INT - PRIMARYKEY   | ID - INT - PRIMARYKEY
| DESCRICAO - VARCHAR(50) | DESCRICAO - VARCHAR(50)
|                         | CATEGORIAID - INT FOREINGKEY (CATEGORIA)

    SELECT SUB.DESCRICAO
           CAT.DESCRICAO
      FROM SUBCATEGORIA SUB
           JOIN CATEGORIA CAT ON CAT.ID = SUB.CATEGORIAID
     ORDER BY CAT.DESCRICAO, SUB.DESCRICAO
```

Este SQL irá trazer todas as SUBCATEGORIA cadastradas e trazer a CATEGORIA que a mesma é relacionada.

Comment: Amigo fiz do jeito que você falou mais acabou retornando o mesmo resultado da que eu tinha feito

Answer (score 0):

esta aqui a minha query;

no caso eu queria ordena por grupos

```
   mysql> SELECT
    -> app.subcategoria.subcategoria,
    -> app.categoria.categoria
    -> FROM
    -> app.ws_subcategoria AS subcategoria
    -> JOIN app.ws_categoria AS categoria
    -> ON app.subcategoria.categoria_id_categoria = app.categoria.id_categoria;
+--------------+-----------+
| subcategoria | categoria |
+--------------+-----------+
| Gasolina     | DESPESAS  |
| Papel        | DESPESAS  |
| VIATURA1     | VIATURAS  |
| VIATURA2     | VIATURAS  |
+--------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

eu teria que passar uma condição WHERE para ordenar por categoria e subcategoria. ?

Comment: Editei o meu post acima, de uma olhada no SQL, é só você usar o ordey by, ele vai ordenar por categoria, e depois por subcategria.